# Read from a file opened with _O_TEMPORARY

Tags: c, windows

Is it possible to write to a file that was created with _O_TEMPORARY and then later read the data that was written to that file? I've tried flushing the buffer, but that doesn't seem to work: subsequent _read() calls still return 0 bytes.

Obviously closing the file after writing and opening it again won't work since closing the file will delete it (that's what _O_TEMPORARY does), so what alternative is there?

Comment: Have you tried changing position in the file with fseek() ?

Comment: I have a file descriptor so I used lseek(), but it worked! thanks!